# PHP array remove all arrays under keyword if found

Tags: php, arrays, explode, keyword

I have 30 lines of text and explode into arrays separate by "\n". the result as follows:

```
[1]=> string(121) "In recent years, the rapid growth" 
[2]=> string(139) "information technology has strongly enhanced computer systems" 
[3]=> string(89) "both in terms of computational and networking capabilities" 
[4]=> string(103) "-------------------------" 
[5]=> string(103) "these novel distributed computing scenarios"
 .
 .
[30]=> string(103) "these computer safety applications. end"
```

in this case, i need to remove all arrays below "-------------" and produce output as follows:

```
[1]=> string(121) "In recent years, the rapid growth" 
[2]=> string(139) "information technology has strongly enhanced computer systems" 
[3]=> string(89) "both in terms of computational and networking capabilities"
```

any idea how to do this? thanks.

solution of the problem by Michael

```
$i = 0;
$new_arr = array();
while ($array[$i] != "-------------------------") {
  // Append lines onto the new array until the delimiter is found
  $new_arr[] = $array[$i];
  $i++;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Comment: use [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/function.array-slice.php) with [array_search](http://php.net/manual/function.array-search.php)

Comment: ill try to use array_slice function. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

###Best solution:
Use `array_search()` and then truncate the array with [`array_splice()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
$key = array_search("-------------------------", $array);
array_splice($array, $key);
```

###Obvious solution:
You can loop over it copying the output to a new array. First example that comes to mind:

```
$i = 0;
$new_arr = array();
while ($array[$i] != "-------------------------") {
  // Append lines onto the new array until the delimiter is found
  $new_arr[] = $array[$i];
  $i++;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
function getMyArray( $array ){

     $myArray = array();
     foreach( $array as $item ){
         if ( $item == '-------------------------' ){ return $myArray; }
         $myArray[] = $line;
     }
     return $myArray'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[array_search](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

and [unset](http://in.php.net/unset)

you can also use array_slice

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    if($value == '-------------')
          break;
    else
          $new_array[$key]=$value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_search` to find the key of where its located.

from PHP.net:

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');
$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
?>
```

Once you have the key, you could do:

```
<?php
while($key < count($array) )
{
   $array = unset($array[$key]);
   $key++;
}
?>
```